# How to detect my tablet is connected to USB and USB is able to read/write

Tags: android, file, usb, android-external-storage

I am using panasonic tablet device which has USB port which allow to connect any pendrive directly to tablet.

My application need to read the data and able to write data to USB.

Sometimes event hough usb is connected, **writing to USB is filing due to loose connection or not mounted properly or usb is not responding**.

So before i start writing something to USB **i want to check is USB in a state to write data or not? and i even wants to know is my device is connected with USB or not at any point of time(lets upon clicking "upload")**.

Comment: Implement a broadcast receiver for `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` and `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED`. In the `onReceive()` you can obtain an uri to a  `File` path for the pen drive.

Comment: But you can do it much simpler. Just display the up to three items returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` to the user and let the user choose one. The third item will be the USB pen drive if the second one is a SD card.

Comment: Having said that you should realize that you mostly will only be able to write to app specific directories on the pen drive. If you want to write everywhere you have to use the `Storage Access Framework` and let the user choose the dirve with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` or such.

Answer (score 1):

you can register broadcast receiver for this.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE");
```

Receiver for this

```
public class USBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")) { 
            //if connected you can read/write data to file.
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest in activity button click?..lets say i want to check connected status or mounted status when i click on "export" button.

My requirement is when user click on export i should do below.

* If the USB is not connected , i have to show info message saying "USB not connected"
* if USB is not in a state to read/write even-though it is connected, i have to show message saying "USB is not in proper state" or some such message
* If it is connected and in a state to write then proceed to write date to USB

Comment: `you can use intentfiler for this.`. Strange wording. You have to register a broadcast receiver for this i would say. And you did not show how to do that.